# cd wslpath as bash function shell quoting problems

Tags: bash, function, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cd, quoting

When using wsl (windows subsystem for linux) I often want to change directory to a windows directory. wslpath takes a windows directory like C:\Windows and converts it to the wsl version /mnt/c/Windows. With a bit of quoting a construct like this works well (although I suspect there are edge cases):

```
cd "`wslpath 'C:\Windows'`"
```

What I want to do is convert this into a bash function that I can put into my .bashrc file to make it a bit easier to type. I want to be able to type something like:

```
wcd 'C:\Windows'
```

The problem is quoting all these quotes so I get what I want. This option fails:

```
wcd ()
{
  cd "`wslpath '$1'`"
}
```

That one was never going to work but I was more hopeful about:

```
wcd ()
{
  cd \"\`wslpath \'$1\'\`\"
}
```

That's about my limit with shell quoting but I'm sure it should be possible to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single quotes prevent variable expansion, so `'$1'` produces the literal string `$1`.

The command substitution is a command boundary, so you can say

```
wcd () { cd "`wslpath "$1"`"; }
```

without bumping into what admittedly can look like the second quote *closing* the string started by the first opening quote, instead of nesting, which you otherwise generally cannot do.

... Though the *vastly* preferred modern command substitution syntax should definitely be used in any new code instead;

```
wcd () { cd "$(wslpath "$1")"; }
```

Kudos for taking care to quote your arguments properly!

Comment: Friends don't let friends use Windows, but you'll get there I hope.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. I always find these tricky once it gets beyond the simple cases, and the new syntax certainly looks much neater.